# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given. when i try to connect my DB as an OOP Object

Tags: php, mysql

I have this Question about connecting my DB to my php and fetch the data. the error is Warning:

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

This is my 2 files the class and the implementation

my code:

```
<?php

class DB{
    //this is my protected data
    protected $db_hostname = 'localhost';
    protected $db_username = 'root';
    protected $db_password = '';
    protected $db_name = 'blog';

    public function connect(){
        //connection to DB
        $connect_db = mysqli_connect($this->db_hostname, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name) or die(mysqli_connect_error($connect_db));
        //close the connection
        mysqli_close($connect_db);
        //for test
        echo "Greate";
    }
}
?>
```

***Second file:-***

```
$connection  = $db->connect();
$result = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts ";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $result) or die(mysqli_error());

//loop through my data 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

  ?>
  <div class="well">
    //print data
    By: <?php echo $row->author ?>
    <p><?php echo $row->title ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>


?>
```

Comment: what does the code in the connect.php file look like. the error is due to the connection having a problem

Comment: Why are you closing the db connection - `mysqli_close($connect_db);` right after opening it? That is like opening then closing a door, and when you walk into the closed door wonder why you slammed your face.

Comment: you are closing connection just after creating it, that's the main problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysqli_query%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+mysqli%2C+null+given

Comment: Also, your `public function connect()` only does `echo "Greate";`. So `$connection  = $db->connect();` is not a valid connection. You need to remove `mysqli_close($connect_db);` and change `echo "Greate";` to `return $connect_db;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function need to be like below:-

```
public function connect(){
   //connection to DB
   $connect_db = mysqli_connect($this->db_hostname, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name);
   if(mysqli_connect_error()){ // you can use mysqli_connect_errorno() also
       die(mysqli_connect_error()); // remove $connect_db
   }else{
     return $connect_db; // return connection object
   }

}
```

Also changed like below:-

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

  ?>
  <div class="well">
    //print data
    By: <?php echo $row['author']; ?>
    <p><?php echo $row['title']; ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>


?>
```

Note:- `mysqli_fetch_array()` will give you both indexed+associative array. While `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` will give you only associative array, which make your resultant array more lighter.Thanks

***Look to it for better error reporting:- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php***

Comment: Thanks a lot i fixed my function just new to php thanks a lot. and also had another mistake with $row->author changed it to $row['author']. cheers

Comment: @Avante   glad to help you

Comment: and also how i make sure the DB is closed safely after i used it  ?

Comment: [*"Returns an object which represents the connection to a MySQL Server"*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php#refsect1-mysqli.construct-returnvalues). At no point does the `mysqli` constructor return a *falsy* value so you cannot use it reliably in an `if` condition

Comment: Much better. You may want to look in to [`mysqli_report`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php). It can be used to get the MySQLi driver to throw exceptions instead of triggering warnings

Comment: @Phil  that was awesome. i am really thankful to you that you shared it. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you set it before creating the connection, the `mysqli` constructor (or `mysqli_connect`) will throw an exception if it cannot connect. This is much easier than checking `connect_error`